# PHP MYSQL Join and output unmatched results

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I've two tables : One called "Collected_items" and the Other "Wrong_Collected"..As shown below :

```
**collected_items**
item_no qty
x1       10
x2       20
BB       5
Z1       20
x13      13


**wrong_collected**
item_no qty
x1      10
x2      20
x13     13
```

As you can see, there are item no.'s occurred on both tables, but all i want is to output the one's which are not found in wrong_collected table.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT collected_items.item_no,wrong_collected.item_no FROM collected_items, wrong_collected WHERE collected_items.item_no!=wrong_collected.item_no");
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
   echo $data["item_no"];
}
```

The output shows all item no.'s except `BB` and `Z1` ..Althout if you remove the `!` from `collected_items.item_no=wrong_collected.item_no` the output will show the matching item_no's as follows :

```
X1 X2 X13
```

Sorry, I'm not really familiar with PHP. I've learned JOIN, but i never saw an example on how to output the unmatched results. Please Help !

Comment: your query is ok and results are perfect then what is the problem ??

Comment: @dianuj Last two paragraphs is what I'm looking for, I want to output the UNMATCHED results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

`SELECT collected_items.item_no,wrong_collected.item_no FROM collected_items, wrong_collected WHERE collected_items.item_no!=wrong_collected.item_no`

to:

```
SELECT ci.item_no FROM collected_items ci 
left join wrong_collected wc on ci.item_no=wc.item_no 
WHERE wc.item_no is null;
```

Comment: It seems your code is missing something, or incorrect. I've received this error message `mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`

Answer (score 0):

use this query:

```
 select * from collected_items ci where not exists (select 1 from wrong_collected wc where ci.item_no = wc.item_no)
```

Comment: I've tried your code, and i got the following error `mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given` .. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `subquery` example which gives the unmatched results

```
SELECT item_no FROM collected_items WHERE item_no  NOT IN 
(SELECT item_no  FROM  wrong_collected)
```

Hope it makes sense

Comment: I would not recommend using subquery if you can achieve the same using joins.

Comment: @geryjuhasz its your recommendation in my answer i have not recommended because you have already posted the answer using `join` so i have provided the different version from your answer